# Swift: Multiplication and brackets calculation doesn't work

Tags: swift, equation-solving

This is a example equation which I want to be solved:

```
let equation = (5-2) * (10-5) / (4-2) * (10-5)
print (equation)
//35
```

The result which is printed is 35. But the right result would be 1,5. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
let numerator: Double = (5-2) * (10-5)
let denumerator: Double = (4-2) * (10-5)
```

Fist you calculate the numerator and denumerator. And finally the result:

```
print(result)
let result: Double = numerator/denumerator
//1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

your expression is incorrect I hope you want the result 1.5
put '(' correctly  * and / Precedence to execution are same but () is greater than * and /

```
let equation = ((5-2) * (10-5)) / ((4-2) * (10-5))
print (equation)
```

if you put the multiplication in another '()' then you will get result one perhaps the right part is integer so its auto conver to integer type

```
let equation = Double ( (5 - 2) * (10 - 5)) / Double ((4 - 2) * ( 10 - 5 ))
print (equation)
```

this code will print 1.5

Just look out operators Precedence  in programming language

Answer (score 0):

As @araf has answered you should look out for the operator precedence in programming language.

Which follow a simple rule of the BODMAS evaluated in following order:

1. Brackets
2. Orders
3. Division and Multiplication (left to right)
4. Addition and Subtraction (left to right)

In your scenario:

```
let equation = (5-2) * (10-5) / (4-2) * (10-5)
```

the output is as follows:

```
3*5/2*4 = 15/2*5 = 7*5 = 35
```

@L.Stephan has suggested a better approach of calculating numerator and denumerator separately and then perform the division part.

To know more you can check this link:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations